# Compile Glasgow Haskell Compiler on Fedora 22

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, haskell

So I want to upgrade "GHC 7.8.4-45" that comes prepackaged with Fedora 22 (courtesy of the [Fedora Haskell SIG](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Haskell_SIG?rd=SIGs/Haskell)) to GHC 7.10.2 (the latest).

How to do that easily?

Comment: Fedora 24 is still on GHC 7.8.4 ... [more precisely](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Haskell_Platform): _"F24 is going to ship with haskell-platform-2014.2 (ghc-7.8.4) .... F25 is planned to ship with haskell-platform-7.10.3 (ghc-7.10.3)"_

Comment: Advantageously, one can get newer versions via [the Fedora Haskell SIG page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Haskell_SIG). At the bottom are listed what is called "Haskell coprs"  (`copr` seems to be the continuous build system, then?). There is a [copr for 7.10.3](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/petersen/ghc-7.10.3/) built by "[petersen](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/petersen/)". The copr repository is enabled using `dnf copr enable petersen/ghc-7.10.3`, but how do I install this upgraded version?

Comment: Here is how: 1) Enable "`dnf copr enable petersen/ghc-7.10.3` 2) Recursively remove all the packages pulled in for fedora package `haskell-platform` using `dnf` (instead of `rpm`, which doesn't provide that option): "`dnf erase haskell-platform`" 3) Re-add packages that might come in handy later: "`dnf install ncurses-c++-libs freeglut-devel`" etc. 4) Just run "`dnf install ghc`". `dnf` will pull the latest ghc from the repository `petersen-ghc-7.10.3` and pull any dependencies from the fedora repo (as that one stays enabled), in my case `ncurses-devel` etc. 5) Win!

Comment: [Fedora 25 comes with GHC 7.10.3](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_for_Developers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Documents & Links

Start-off info source is at [haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org/downloads)

One can install by:

- Using the Haskell "Platform" installer.

  - [Haskell-Platform GitHub README](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform)
  - [Per-system indications on what to use](https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html#linux-fedora) (for Fedora, basically, `dnf install haskell-platform`, which is not what we want as this just means installing the older version).
  - [A discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2w3php/venerable_haskell_platform_necessity_or_product/) about "Platform" at Reddit.
- Using the Haskell "Stack" packager provided by [stackage.org](https://www.stackage.org/) ("Stackage is a stable source of Haskell packages...part of an initiative by the commercial Haskell group")

  - [commercialhaskell/stack
    GitHub README](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/install_and_upgrade.md)
  - [Docs at haskellstack.org](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/)
- Build it ourselves (and we need Haskell to build Haskell)

  - The instructions on [building and porting](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building) at haskell.org seem invaluable.

Furthermore:

- At the [Glasgow Haskell Compiler page](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/) we find the [latest stable release](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download) as well as [distribution packages for Fedora](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/distribution_packages#fedora). You can also jump right into the file tree [here for the latest ghc 7.10.x](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10-latest/)
- Fedora packages are maintained by the [Fedora Haskell SIG](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Haskell_SIG?rd=SIGs/Haskell) which also has a page about [packaging of Haskell projects](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Haskell).

## So...

We shall build the Glasgow Haskell Compiler `ghc` using the [Haskell-Platform](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform) installer.

### Fix some libraries

We will have to use the precompiled, latest [`Cabal` package tool](https://github.com/haskell/cabal)  instead of the system `Cabal`. Unfortunately it comes in 32-bit only.

You may want to uninstall an existing `Cabal` (we will set the `PATH` to the new `Cabal` later, so this is not strictly necessary)

```
# as root
dnf erase cabal-install cabal-install-static ghc-Cabal-devel
```

On 64-bit system, we need 32-bit versions of libraries for the new `Cabal`:

```
# as root
dnf install glibc.i686 zlib.i686 gmp-devel.i686 gmp.i686
```

To compile `ghc`, we need 64-bit `gmp-devel`:

```
# as root
dnf install gmp-devel.x86_64
```

Check that both 32-bit and 64-bit are installed using:

```
rpm --query gmp-devel
> gmp-devel-6.0.0-9.fc22.i686
> gmp-devel-6.0.0-9.fc22.x86_64
```

The precompiled `ghc` for CentOS, which we will download later, will be looking for `libgmp.3` at some point, so we need a symlink:

```
# as root
cd /usr/lib64
ln -s libgmp.so.10.2.0 libgmp.so.3
```

### Install additional packages

There will be complaints about missing Z libraries and 3D libraries. So:

```
# as root
dnf install zlib-devel
dnf install freeglut freeglut-devel
```

And maybe:

```
# as root
dnf install ncurses-devel libffi-devel
```

"libffi" (foreign function interface) seems interesting.

Anyway, you need `make` (GNU make):

```
# as root
dnf install make
```

### Add special user who will run the build process

We will build as the user `builder`, not as `root`:

```
# as root
useradd builder
```

### Add old `ghc` which comes as Fedora 22 package

We need the `ghc` that comes with Fedora 22 to kickstart compilation. According to the `Platform` [README](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform), `ghc` has to be > 7.4 (Fedora has `ghc` 7.8.4).

```
# as root
dnf install ghc
```

This pulls in 55 packages, including `libffi-devel` if it wasn't there yet.

You also need:

```
# as root
dnf install ghc-split
```

Or you will get the error:

```
> cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
> hastache >=0.6.0, shake >=0.14, split -any, text -any
```

### Add a new precompiled `Cabal`

As mentioned. you have to install the precompiled `Cabal` to replace the older one which comes with Fedora 22.

Indeed using `Cabal` 1.18.1.0 which comes with Fedora will eventually give an error:

```
> ghc: ghc no longer supports single-file style package databases
> (dist/package.conf.inplace) use 'ghc-pkg init' to create the
> database with the correct format.
```

Become user `builder`:

```
su - builder
```

Get the new `Cabal` from [the cabal download page](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html), but as said above it currently comes only in 32-bit.

```
# as builder
cd
wget https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-install-1.22.0.0/cabal-1.22.0.0-i386-unknown-linux.tar.gz
# 3.84 MiB; just contains the "cabal" binary
tar xzf cabal-1.22.0.0-i386-unknown-linux.tar.gz 
mkdir cabalbin
mv cabal cabalbin/
```

### Add a recent precompiled `ghc`

We need a prepackaged "bindist" (precompiled `ghc`) for compilation, which is passed as argument to the Haskell `Platform`.

The latest one can be found [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_10_2) - take the "CentOS" one.

```
# as builder
cd
wget http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64-unknown-linux-centos66.tar.bz2
```

No need to uncompress or untar the 131.82 MiB tarball.

### Tune `Platform`

Checking the [README](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform):

*If you are building for a Posix like system (Linux, or BSD), then you can add the command line option --prefix to specify where, on the target system the tree of built things will be placed. It defaults to "/usr/local/haskell".  The build will include another directory under that named "ghc-x.y.z-arch" and everything will be installed under there.*

... so we don't tune anything because `/usr/local/haskell` sounds exactly like what we want.

And also:

*Adding -j [n] to the build invocation will enable building on multiple cores at once.*

It tried this but it doesn't seem to work...

### Get `Platform`

Clone `Platform` from github into a ".sav" directory. This is needed because compilation may fail, and in that case you just want to blow away what was done and start over:

```
# as builder
cd
git clone https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform
mv haskell-platform haskell-platform.sav
```

Fix the PATH of user `builder`! At some point, the latest, compiled `ghc` has to be used instead of the one with comes with the system!

As user `builder`, edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add:

```
PATH=$HOME/cabalbin/:$HOME/haskell-platform/build/ghc-bindist/local/bin/:$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

As set up earlier `$HOME/cabalbin` contains a fresh `Cabal` and at some time `$HOME/haskell-platform/build/ghc-bindist/local/bin/` will contain the latest `ghc`.

Logout/Login to use the new PATH.

### Build

Now start building using

```
# as builder
cd
/bin/rm -rf haskell-platform 
cp -a haskell-platform.sav haskell-platform 
cd haskell-platform
./platform.sh ../ghc-7.10.2-x86_64-unknown-linux-centos66.tar.bz2
```

This build should actually succeed but may take about 20 minutes on a not-slow machine. Then you see:

```
> To install this build:
> 1) copy build/product/haskell-platform-7.10.2-a-unknown-posix-x86_64.tar.gz to the target machine
> 2) untar it (creates files in the working directory)
> 3) as root, run the script ./install-haskell-platform.sh
> Build completed in 22:54m
> # tar (for build/product/hp-usr-local.tar.gz)
> # cp (for build/product/haskell-platform-7.10.2-a-unknown-posix-x86_64.tar.gz)
> # tar (for build/product/haskell-platform-7.10.2-a-unknown-posix-x86_64.tar.gz)
```

### Install

Proceed as described above

```
# as root
cp ~builder/haskell-platform/build/product/haskell-platform-7.10.2-a-unknown-posix-x86_64.tar.gz ~
cd
tar xzf haskell-platform-7.10.2-a-unknown-posix-x86_64.tar.gz
./install-haskell-platform.sh
```

You see:

```
> Unpacking ./hp-usr-local.tar.gz to /...
> Running /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/activate-hs ...
> 
> Haskell set to:
> GHC         /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64
> Haddocks    file:///usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/doc/frames.html
> Other doc   file:///usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/share/doc/ghc/html/index.html
> 
> Symlinks for command line tools (ghc, cabal, etc..) added to:
> /usr/local/bin
```

Symlinks will have been installed to `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
> activate-hs -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/activate-hs
> alex -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/alex
> cabal -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/cabal
> ghc -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/ghc
> ghc-7.10.2 -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/ghc-7.10.2
> ghci -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/ghci
> ghci-7.10.2 -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/ghci-7.10.2
> ghc-pkg -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/ghc-pkg
> ghc-pkg-7.10.2 -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/ghc-pkg-7.10.2
> haddock -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/haddock
> haddock-ghc-7.10.2 -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/haddock-ghc-7.10.2
> happy -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/happy
> hp2ps -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/hp2ps
> hpc -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/hpc
> hsc2hs -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/hsc2hs
> HsColour -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/HsColour
> runghc -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/runghc
> runghc-7.10.2 -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/runghc-7.10.2
> runhaskell -> /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/bin/runhaskell
```

In principle, we can get rid of the existing packages of `ghc` (the command below only works if you give `-y` to the `dnf erase`)

```
rpm --query --all | grep -e '^ghc-' | xargs dnf erase
```

### Run Test Suite

It is a good idea to run the test suite.

Indeed, I am hitting some errors currently...

These will go into [GHC Trac home](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc)

See  "[running tests](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/RunningTests)" at haskell.org for generic instructions.

To run tests, one has to install the test suite source from [this page](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_10_2#sources) "on top of" the source tree created by the build:

```
# as builder
cd
# the '..' below is not a typo!
cd ./haskell-platform/build/ghc-bindist/ghc-7.10.2/..
wget http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/ghc-7.10.2-testsuite.tar.bz2
bunzip2 ghc-7.10.2-testsuite.tar.bz2
tar xf ghc-7.10.2-testsuite.tar
```

You may want to install additional cabal packages to run certain tests. Some may already have been installed. Run:

```
# as builder
## To install hmatrix you will probably have to perform, as root:
## dnf install blas-devel lapack-devel
# Linear systems, matrix decompositions, and other numerical computations
cabal install hmatrix 
# Monad classes using functional dependencies
cabal install mtl
# This package provides a library for parallel programming.
cabal install parallel
# Parsec is designed as an industrial-strength parser library.
cabal install parsec 
# various primitive memory-related operations
cabal install primitive
# library for random testing of program properties.
cabal install QuickCheck
# provides a basic random number generation library
cabal install random
# one module layer over regex-posix to replace Text.Regex
cabal install regex-compat  
# the generics system described in the "Scrap Your Boilerplate" papers
cabal install syb
# A UTF8 layer for Strings
cabal install utf8-string 
# An efficient implementation of Int-indexed arrays
cabal install vector
```

Run `cabal info $PACKAGE` to get package info. The package configuration goes to `~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.10.2/package.conf.d/`, the package contents go to `~/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.2/$PACKAGE`.

Then [start tests](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/RunningTests/Running). We will capture the output to `~/test_output.txt`:

```
# as builder
cd
cd ./haskell-platform/build/ghc-bindist/ghc-7.10.2
make test 2>&1 | tee ~/test_output.txt
```

After some time, you get output:

```
> Unexpected results from:
> TEST="T9203 T9961 parsing001 T9675 T6048"
> 
> OVERALL SUMMARY for test run started at Mon Oct 26 17:52:52 2015 CET
>  0:33:17 spent to go through
>     4142 total tests, which gave rise to
>    15728 test cases, of which
>    11883 were skipped
> 
>       45 had missing libraries
>     3754 expected passes
>       41 expected failures
> 
>        0 caused framework failures
>        0 unexpected passes
>        0 unexpected failures
>        5 unexpected stat failures
> 
> Unexpected stat failures:
>    perf/compiler    T6048 [stat not good enough] (optasm)
>    perf/compiler    T9675 [stat not good enough] (optasm)
>    perf/compiler    T9961 [stat not good enough] (normal)
>    perf/compiler    parsing001 [stat too good] (normal)
>    perf/should_run  T9203 [stat too good] (normal)
```

Comment: Accepting my own answer here. This question sure is meeting with indifference...